# Type information for a conditional property in JSDoc

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

I'm adding type information for TypeScript to an existing JavaScript library via JSDoc. I have a constructor function that might set a property based on the value(s) of the parameter(s) it's given:

```js
/**
 * Settings you can use to configure an instance of an {@link ExampleClass}
 *
 * @typedef {Object} ExampleOptions
 * @property {true} [option] You can set this to `true` to make a property on an instance of {@link ExampleClass} exist. If you don't set it, that property won't exist
 */

/**
 * A thing that does stuff
 * 
 * @constructor
 * @param {ExampleOptions} [param] Options you can use to configure the new instance
 */
function ExampleClass(param) {
    if(param.option === true) {
        /**
         * A property that only exists based on the options given to this constructor
         *
         * @type {boolean}
         */
        this.property = true;
    }
}
```

I was hoping that TypeScript would externally interpret the declaration of `property` to be like `property?: boolean;`, but it looks like it gets interpreted to be non-optional, and comes up in the autocomplete in my editor without having to check for its existence ahead of time. Ideally, I'd like for it to be an optional property that you'd have to check for before you can use it, or even allow you to use it unchecked if TypeScript can somehow guarantee that you had passed `{option: true}` to the constructor. How can I make that work?

Comment: Why can't you make the property always exist? Seems doable as the "default" value is falsey anyways (undefined)

Comment: It's an existing library that I don't really control except for in the open source sense, so I'd like to make as few code-level changes to this as possible and try to stick to making documentation additions only as much as I can. `undefined` is falsey, but I'd like to communicate to TypeScript as best as I can the cases where you can expect it to exist and which ones you can't

Comment: Does adding a "?" after boolean give you what you expect? Something like `@type {boolean?}`

Comment: It does not, unfortunately. The JSDoc way to signal optionality as I understand it is usually to have a trailing `=` like `@type {boolean=}`, but that doesn't seem to do anything, either. I actually just checked to see if doing `@type {boolean | undefined}` would at least make it optional, but it looks like TypeScript ignores the `undefined` even in that case, which makes me wonder if this is a bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pre-declare the class with a `@typedef` with the optional properties and set it to the constructor as a variable of type `{new () => ExampleClass}`. This way it's even possible to declare `this` as the defined class and have code completion inside the constructor function itself. Something like the below:

```js
/**
 * Settings you can use to configure an instance of an {@link ExampleClass}
 *
 * @typedef {Object} ExampleOptions
 * @property {true} [option] You can set this to `true` to make a property on an instance of {@link ExampleClass} exist. If you don't set it, that property won't exist
 */

/**
 * @typedef {object} ExampleClass
 * @prop {boolean} [property] A property that only exists based on the options given to this constructor
 */

/**
 * A thing that does stuff
 *
 * @constructor
 * @param {ExampleOptions} [param] Options you can use to configure the new instance
 * @this {ExampleClass}
 * @type {{new () => ExampleClass}}
 */
const ExampleClass = function (param) {
    if(param.option === true) {
        this.property = true;
    }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just do

```
interface options {
   option? : boolean;
}

/**
 * A thing that does stuff
 * 
 * @constructor
 * @param {options} [param] Options you can use to configure the new instance
 */
function ExampleClass(param : options) {
    if(param.option === true) {
        /**
         * A property that only exists based on the options given to this constructor
         *
         * @type {boolean}
         */
        this.property = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that it's a JavaScript file, not a TypeScript file, and I don't wanna convert it to TypeScript

Comment: I see, sorry I misunderstood that from the question